# Python beeware: Unable to code sign with “briefcase package --adhoc-sign“

Tags: python, macos, code-signing, beeware

I'm working on packaging a macOS app with Beeware and attempting to use the --adhoc-sign option for local code signing, as outlined in the Beeware [documentation](https://docs.beeware.org/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial-3.html). This step is essential for testing the app on my local machine before distribution. However, during the packaging process, I encounter an error related to code signing that prevents the completion of the process.

Here's the command I'm running and the error message I receive:

Help is very welcome!

```
(beeware-venv) tk@lanhost171 workhard % briefcase package --adhoc-sign

[workhard] Signing app with ad-hoc identity...
Because you are signing with the ad-hoc identity, this app will run, but cannot be re-distributed.
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 100.0% • 00:05

Unable to code sign /Users/tk/Desktop/beeware-tutorial/workhard/build/workhard/macos/app/workhard.app.

Log saved to /Users/tk/Desktop/beeware-tutorial/workhard/logs/briefcase.2024_03_11-23_47_19.package.log
```

the log file is too long to post it here... but here some snippets:

```
Date/Time:       2024-03-11 23:23:25 
Command line:    /Users/tk/Desktop/beeware-tutorial/beeware-venv/bin/briefcase package --adhoc-sign

OS Release:      Darwin 20.6.0
OS Version:      Darwin Kernel Version 20.6.0: Wed Jun 23 00:26:31 PDT 2021; root:xnu-7195.141.2~5/RELEASE_X86_64
Architecture:    x86_64
Platform:        macOS-11.5.2-x86_64-i386-64bit

Python exe:      /Users/tk/Desktop/beeware-tutorial/beeware-venv/bin/python
Python version:  3.8.2 (default, Apr  8 2021, 23:19:18)  [Clang 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)]
Virtual env:     True
Conda env:       False

Briefcase:       0.3.17
Target platform: macOS
Target format:   app

Environment Variables:
    HOME=/Users/tk
    LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
    LOGNAME=tk
    OLDPWD=/Users/tk/Desktop/beeware-tutorial
    PATH=/Users/tk/Desktop/beeware-tutorial/beeware-venv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
    PS1=(beeware-venv) %n@%m %1~ %# 
    PWD=/Users/tk/Desktop/beeware-tutorial/workhard
    SHELL=/bin/zsh
    SHLVL=1
    SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.BEWhTNx5sV/Listeners
    TERM=xterm-256color
    TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
    TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=440
    TERM_SESSION_ID=7A603702-FB56-4C80-AD53-4D319FD51C12
    TMPDIR=/var/folders/cm/df7c__mj1wsd4yg10tqfq84w0000gn/T/
    USER=tk
    VIRTUAL_ENV=/Users/tk/Desktop/beeware-tutorial/beeware-venv
    XPC_FLAGS=0x0
    XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
    _=/Users/tk/Desktop/beeware-tutorial/beeware-venv/bin/briefcase
    __CFBundleIdentifier=com.apple.Terminal
    __CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING=0x1F5:0x0:0x3
    __PYVENV_LAUNCHER__=/Users/tk/Desktop/beeware-tutorial/beeware-venv/bin/python
```

```
│ │          errors = '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/codesign_allocate: fatal error: file'+397      


CalledProcessError: Command '['codesign', '/Users/tk/Desktop/beeware-tutorial/workhard/build/workhard/macos/app/workhard.app', '--sign', '-', '--force', '--entitlements', '/Users/tk/Desktop/beeware-tutorial/workhard/build/workhard/macos/app/Entitlements.plist']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:


 /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/concurrent/futures/thread.py:57 in run                                       │
│                                                                                                                                                                                  │
│    54 │   │   │   return                                                                       ╭── locals ───╮                                                                   │
│    55 │   │                                                                                    │ self = None │                                                                   │
│    56 │   │   try:                                                                             ╰─────────────╯                                                                   │
│ ❱  57 │   │   │   result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)                                                                                                                    │
│    58 │   │   except BaseException as exc:                                                                                                                                       │
│    59 │   │   │   self.future.set_exception(exc)                                                                                                                                 │
│    60 │   │   │   # Break a reference cycle with the exception 'exc'                                                                                                             │
│                                                                                                                                                                                  │
│ /Users/tk/Desktop/beeware-tutorial/beeware-venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/briefcase/platforms/macOS/__init__.py:452 in sign_file                                   │
│                                                                                                                                                                                  │
│   449 │   │   │   │   )                                                                                                                                                          │
│   450 │   │   │   │   return                                                                                                                                                     │
│   451 │   │   │   else:                                                                                                                                                          │
│ ❱ 452 │   │   │   │   raise BriefcaseCommandError(f"Unable to code sign {path}.")                                                                                                │
│   453 │                                                                                                                                                                          │
│   454 │   def sign_app(self, app, identity):                                                                                                                                     │
│   455 │   │   """Sign an entire app with a specific identity.
```

Comment: I don't think these snippets contain enough information to answer the question. You'll probably get more help by creating an issue on the [Briefcase GitHub page](https://github.com/beeware/briefcase/issues), and attaching the full log file.

Comment: To sign ad-hoc, the identity should be simply given as `-`(the minus sign)